# JSON data containing `\\\` in between

Tags: python, json, http, flask

I have a python listening server written as a Flask application.This server is listening to POST messages from a remote source.The remote source is posting JSON documents. A sample JSON document that I recieved is shown below.

```
{

    "Timestamp": "1432241553492",
    "data": "[{\"EventName\":\"Time\",\"Category\":\"Experience\",\"Severity\":\"warn\",\"Subject\":\"Time\",\"Message\":\"details:{\\\"Message\\\":\\\"https://xxxx.xxxxx.com/ (1882 ms : ATime: 5 ms, BTime: 1108 ms, CTime: 769 ms), \\\",\\\"Time\\\":\\\"Fri May 22 2015 08:52:33 GMT+1200 (NZST)\\\",\\\"MobileDevice\\\":\\\"Not Mobile\\\",\\\"User\\\":\\\"user.name\\\",\\\"CPUs\\\":8,\\\"Language\\\":\\\"en-GB\\\",\\\"isEvent\\\":\\\"true\\\",\"Stamp\":\"1432241553492\"}]",
    "msgType": "0",
    "tid": "1"
}
```

This file is supposed to be a proper JSON file.But I get `\\\` in between the fields as shown above.I am wondering if something is wrong with the setting of Http OPTIONS in my listening server or the data type perhaps.
It would be great if someone can help me to figure it out.

Comment: i heard you like json so I put json in your json in your json?

Comment: also, that part `details:` is not valid (the key `details` is not quoted)

Comment: Are you sure that’s exactly the output? Then it’s just wrong.

Comment: What you have there is *not valid JSON*.

Comment: @poke - I have removed some sensitive content.Probably got it slightly wrong.But the idea is there are `\\\` across the JSON file which I am not expecting.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I agree that it may not be valid JSON.But my question is about `\\\` characters which I am not expecting. Am trying to figure out what might be causing it.

Comment: @liv2hak: start by explaining what produces the file. Right now it is *just a string*. We can't know any more about how it was produced than you because you didn't tell us how you got it.

Comment: Well, if you removed stuff, then you likely broke it. The thing is that inside that JSON object, the `data` property contains another string which contains JSON you need to parse, and within that object’s `details` property, there is yet another JSON object which you also need to parse separately.

Comment: @liv2hak: the backslashes are otherwise valid escapes in a JSON string object, but you have a quote that is *not* escaped that breaks the whole thing. It is rather a mess.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I checked my original ouput with jsonlint.It does seem to be valid JSON.didn't know that backslashes were valid escapes in JSON. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

At first glance you appear to have a botched JSON file; there is a stray `,"` sequence in there that breaks the format.

If you removed entries, it may well be that you broke the format; if your actual string validates on http://jsonlint.com then you did just that.

Backslashes are valid escape sequences in JSON. You have data that contains other JSON strings, which in turn contain *more* encoded JSON data. You can recursively decode those:

```
>>> import json
>>> print json.dumps({'object': 'deeply nested'})
{"object": "deeply nested"}
>>> print json.dumps({'wrapper': json.dumps({'object': 'deeply nested'})})
{"wrapper": "{\"object\": \"deeply nested\"}"}
>>> print json.dumps({'outermost': json.dumps({'wrapper': json.dumps({'object': 'deeply nested'})})})
{"outermost": "{\"wrapper\": \"{\\\"object\\\": \\\"deeply nested\\\"}\"}"}
```

Note that as the level of wrapping increases, so do the backslashes. First the embedded `"` quotes get escaped to `\"`, followed by escaping of the backslash and the quote to `\\\"`, etc.

You probably want to fix the code that produces this nesting. Don't encode individual objects, then store them in something else.

*Don't* do this:

```
event['details'] = json.dumps(event_detail_data)
message['data'] = json.dumps(event)
json_to_send = json.dumps(message)
```

That'd create a nested structure. Only encode the final object:

```
event['details'] = event_detail_data
message['data'] = event
json_to_send = json.dumps(message)
```

Comment: @Martin Pieters - Is there a way to convert this to a more human friendly format. The original data at the source doesn't have the `\\\`. But the data is same.

Comment: @liv2hak: so how did you *encode* that data? Don't encode the individual pieces, encode only the final dictionary to JSON. You haven't told us anything about how you are *producing* this object.

Comment: I don't have control on how the JSON is created.I have to decode it at my end though.